# Facebook Graph search API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Background:
I'm an employee of a public figure who is constantly getting facebook scam impersonations. I'm going to automate the process of checking facebook for new scams by having a script search facebook each day and report any new users and pages for his name. I'm modifying an old FB app that I created years ago to run the process.

Problem:
I noticed that I can search for "page" on facebook's graph api with my app, but "user" comes back with: "**Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource.**" I assume this is a permissions error so I try to add an &Access_Token= with all permissions from (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to the URL with no luck.

Here's my PHP script:

```
require '../src/facebook.php';<BR>

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => '**I_removed_this_code**',
'secret' => '**I_removed_this_code**'));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');<BR>
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

$fb_response = $facebook->api('/search?q=**Public_Figure_Name**&type=page'); //<--change this to user and it doesnt work
print_r(array_values($fb_response));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic issue is that only users an app has access to are either users of the app or (given proper friend permissions) friends of users of the app.

However, if you were to act as you, using an SSO token, 'you' would have a user token and can do graph searches.

PS. I would have added this as a comment but my rep's not high enough.

Comment: this is good info. Thanks. If you can give me a bit more info about the "you" code, and I get it working I'll give you credit

Comment: Here is a link to Facebook's [User Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens) authentication. It's been a while so I don't have any of that code handy but there are a lot of tutorials on how to acquire them. For your case, I would build a light-weight login dialog with a search query/button instead of using a long-lived token.  Edit: I didn't realize how difficult that link was to read, the whole url is : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#usertokens

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm familiar with how to get the token, but using it in the code, I'm not. I try to add an &Access_Token= with all permissions from (developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to the URL with no luck. I'm guessing this must be incorrect. Edit: Ideally, I don't want to have to re-authenticate this automated process each time it runs

Comment: Due to your help, I figured out that I needed to add this code:

if (!$user) {
    $params = array('redirect_uri' => 'http://_REDIRECT_URL.php','scope' => 'read_stream,friends_likes,publish_stream,user_photos');
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
    echo '<a href="' . $login_url . '">Login</a>';
    exit();
}

Answer (score 0):

If I try the following in the Graph Explorer, it works without problem:

```
/search?q=Tom%20Cruise&type=user
```

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3DTom%2520Cruise%26type%3Duser&version=v2.2

The Search API is documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search which describes exactly your behaviour (distinction between page and user search).